# Solr speeding up large or boolean filter

Tags: performance, solr, filter, lucene

I'm currently using solr 4.2.1 with approximately 10 mln documents in the index.

The index is updated frequently.

I'm using EDisMaxQueryParser with filter_query. The filter_query is just a one big boolean or query by id.

fq=id:(1 2 3 4 ... 50950)

ids list is always different and not sequential.

The problem is that query performance not so well, as you can imagine.

In some particular cases i'm able to do filtering based on different fields, but sometimes (like 30-40% of all queries) i'm still end up with this large id filter.

I'm looking for the ways to improve this query performance.

It doesn't seem like solr join could be applied there.

Another option would be to somehow cover the whole interval with subsets and switch to range filter queries. But I couldn't say that this is an easy solutions and also probably not the optimal one.

Is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem  - I'm having the problem of "security filter lists".
So what you should do:

1. Write your own custom QParserPlugin + QParser and use Lucene's FieldCacheTermsFilter
2. Disable caching for this filter
3. Use it as a PostFilter in case your are having different filters.

Details:

- http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-large-boolean-filter-td4070747.html#a4070964
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/custom-security-filtering-solr